# Where can a virus or other malware "hide" on common PC and Mac hardware?

Tags: antivirus, antimalware, threat-mitigation, bios

I'm looking for a detailed list of locations that viruses can "hide" in modern hardware even after a reboot.

Some things that come to mind include

- Boot BIOS/Firmware
- [CPU Microcode](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29730/396)
- Connected PCI components that have a reprogrammable BIOS
- Some [keyboards](http://www.digitalsociety.org/2009/08/apple-keyboards-hacked-and-possessed/)
- Hard coded [directly into hardware](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/24825/396)
- ??Some graphics cards?? <-- speculation
- BIOS of locally attached printer?? <-- speculation

Comment: Anything with ROM or EEPROM; anything with ASICs that have not been meticulously checked? Would rely on vulnerabilities in drivers and OS to spread, for sure. I would v.much like to see the list of locations where the malware **cannot** hide, though. A nightmarish thing would be malware in HSMs (cue evil cackling and camera zooming to a hand with a fat white cat)

Comment: Don't forget they can hide in plain sight if they have had a chance to edit your kernel. You wouldn't even see a change in disk space usage.

Answer (score 2):

How about Firewire DMA? Firewire (a.k.a. "IEEE 1394") allows [direct memory access by at least some kinds of devices](http://www.breaknenter.org/projects/inception/).  People have writte l[ots of attack tools for lots of devices](http://www.hermann-uwe.de/blog/physical-memory-attacks-via-firewire-dma-part-1-overview-and-mitigation) over the years, so it should be possible to hide in a Firewire device.

To confirm your PCI device hypothesis, it [looks like](http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-dc-07/Heasman/Paper/bh-dc-07-Heasman-WP.pdf) John Heasman implemented a PCI rootkit, which pretty much has all the properties you'd need to write a virus.

Another place: the ACPI BIOS. John Heasman also seems to have [implemented an ACPI rootkit](http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-europe-06/bh-eu-06-Heasman.pdf).  The presentation gives example code fragments for other evil things.